# file handling python - vlookup

Tags: python, file-handling

source.csv as follows.

```
AB;CD
a;1;
b;2;
c;3;
```

target.csv as follows.

```
DE;FG;HI
1;e;1;
2;a;2;
3;f;3;
```

I need to do a vlookup using file handling mechanisms in python.
So need to update column `'FG'` of `'target.csv'` by looking up the column `'AB'` of `'source.csv'` and update with `'CD'` column value of `'source.csv'`.

So my desired output is like below.

```
DE;FG;HI
1;e;1;
2;1;2; #a is replaced with 1
3;f;3;
```

Without using pandas or any other method how I can approach this.
Below is how I approached this.

```
with open('D:/target.csv', "w+", encoding="utf-8") as Tgt_csvFile:
    with open('D:/source.csv', "r", encoding="utf-8") as Src_csvFile:
        
        for line in Src_csvFile:
            
            fields = line.split(";")
            x = fields[0]
            
            for line_1 in Tgt_csvFile:
                fields_1 = line_1.split(";")
                y = fields[1]
                if y == x:
                    update # not sure how to do this
                else:
                    keep as it is
```

Appreciate on the support

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your particular problem, but if the number of input/output columns changes you will need to adjust the logic accordingly.

It's also worth noting the trailing `;` on each non-header row of your csv file will cause most packages to assume there is an extra column.  I don't think you want that.

```
# Read in input, creating a dict where key is column 1 and value is column 2
with open('source.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';')
    s = {x[0]:x[1] for x in reader}
print(s)    

# If column 2 is a key in dict s update with value from dict
output = []
with open('target.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] in s.keys():
            row[1] = s[row[1]]
        output.append(row)
        
# Output to csv
with open('output.csv', mode='w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(output)
```

Comment: Have you used a new csv called output.csv?

Comment: It's creating that as a new file that contains the updated data.  You could change it to target.csv or wherever you want to write the updated data to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
with open('D:/source.csv', "r", encoding="utf-8") as Src_csvFile:
    l=Src_csvFile.readlines()
    d={}
    for i in l[1:]:
        x=i.split(';')
        d[x[0]]=x[1]

with open('D:/target.csv', "r", encoding="utf-8") as Tgt_csvFile:
    m=Tgt_csvFile.readlines()
    for i in range(1,len(m)):
        x=m[i].split(';')
        if x[1] in d:
            x[1]=d.get(x[1])
        m[i]=';'.join(x)

with open('D:/target.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as Tgt_csvFile:
    Tgt_csvFile.writelines(m)
```

Output:

```
DE;FG;HI
1;e;1;
2;1;2; 
3;f;3;
```